# Pressing Tab Key in Terminal Enters a Space Instead of Triggering Autocomplete

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, autocomplete

First time asking on this site, please let me know if I can improve the question :)

I'm helping a student configure her mac development environment.

We've got zsh setup, which I believe should come with the ability to autocomplete folder and file names.

For example, I'd like to be able to type `cd tes` and have it autocomplete `cd test_folder`.

This is the default behavior for me, however on her machine anytime you press Tab while in the mac terminal, it instead creates a space, the same as if you had pressed the SpaceBar. This seems to prevent autocompletion.

Based on some tutorials I've tried editing `~/.inputrc` to add

```
set completion-ignore-case on
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
TAB: menu-complete
```

I've also tried using a bash shell, the environment doesn't seem to matter. Tab always creates a space. I've also considered changing the command to trigger autocomplete, but couldn't get that working. I even tried plugging in a separate keyboard and making sure CAPS_LOCK and NUM_LOCK are not part of the problem.

Help much appreciated if you have thoughts on what could be going wrong here!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manipulating the `.inputrc` manipulate the `.zshrc` with code below:-

```
bindkey '       ' autosuggest-accept
```

**Here** the space b/w the double quotes is the `Tab` key pressed.

Link to zsh documentation where you can get a better & detailed idea
https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions#key-bindings

Comment: Thank you! I will send this to the student and give it a try :)

Comment: Everything is working now! However, the error was between the keyboard and the chair on this one but thank you for your time. We had a miscommunication between the tab key and the space bar. The woes of teaching remote where I can't see the student's keyboard.